# Make WordPress API Call Using RCurl/HTTR

Tags: r, wordpress, curl, oauth, httr

I am looking to make an API call to grab the post data of a protected WP blog. I am having some trouble translating the WP authentication procedure from PHP to R, I think in part because I don't fully understand the process.

My understanding of the OAuth token receipt procedure comes from [this page](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/oauth2/):

1. Send user to an authorization endpoint that prompts a login:
   `https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=your_client_id&redirect_uri=your_url&response_type=code&blog=1234`
2. Then make a `POST` request at the API with the code in the above redirect url incorporated:

`$curl = curl_init('https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/token');
   curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        'client_id' => your_client_id,
        'redirect_uri' => your_redirect_url,
        'client_secret' => your_client_secret_key,
        'code' => $_GET['code'], // The code from the previous request
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
    ) );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $auth = curl_exec( $curl );
    $secret = json_decode($auth);
    $access_key = $secret->access_token;`

which then returns:

```
{
    "access_token": "YOUR_API_TOKEN",
    "blog_id": "blog ID",
    "blog_url": "blog url",
    "token_type": "bearer"
}
```

but I have no idea where to start in r. I apologize that this is not a reproducible problem. I tried to use the code [here](https://github.com/hadley/httr/blob/master/demo/oauth2-azure.r), but I can't quite figure out what went wrong:

```
app_name <- 'myapp' 
client_id <- 'your_client_id'
redirect_uri <- 'your_redirect_url'
client_secret <- 'your_client_secret_key'
resource_uri <- #IDK what this is

oauth_endpoint(authorize = "https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=your_client_id&redirect_uri=your_url&response_type=code&blog=1234",
access = "https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/token")
wordpress_endpoint <- oauth_endpoints('wordpress')

# Create the app instance.
myapp <- oauth_app(key = 'your_client_id',
                   secret = 'your_client_secret_key')

mytoken <- oauth2.0_token(wordpress_endpoint, myapp,
                          user_params = list(resource = resource_uri),
                          use_oob = FALSE)
```

Comment: After searching the web for examples of using `httr` to authenticate with various APIs and putting together some code that ultimately doesn't quite work, I understand the frustration of being stuck. Please post the code you've tried so far, so that we can assist you going forward.

Comment: So I've updated the question with what I've attempted so far, but I am not quite sure if I understand `httr`. Do you have to use one of the 'pre-loaded' APIs in the package (_e.g.,_ `ouath_endpoints("google")`)?

Answer (score 0):

There are built in endpoints for certain APIs... so you don't have to get the URLs yourself. I don't thing wordpress is one of them, so that's what you are creating for yourself with the `oauth_endpoint` call. Something like this might work... but I don't have a wordpress account to test it...

```
wordpress <- oauth_endpoint(authorize = "https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=your_client_id&redirect_uri=your_url&response_type=token&blog=1234",
                            access = "https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/token")

myapp <- oauth_app(key = 'your_client_id',
                   secret = 'your_client_secret_key')

mytoken <- oauth2.0_token(wordpress, myapp)
```

Comment: So when I run that code in R it gives this message `Invalid request, please go back and try again.
Error Code: invalid_request
Error Message: Mismatch in redirect_uri.` 
But when I run the authorization address in a browser it brings me to the WP authorization page...